# cv::Mat causes crash when assigned to with 'at<unsigned char>(0,0)'

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following simple bit of code that is crashing and it's not immediately clear to me why this shouldn't work.

```
cv::Mat *test_bug = new cv::Mat(img->rows, img->cols, CV_32F);
test_bug->at<unsigned char>(0,0) = 4;
```

`test_bug` ends up being a 207 by 207 matrix..so I know that the array index is valid.    This is the copy/paste error.

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 <
>   (unsigned)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) <
>   (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211)
>
> > > ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in unknown function, file
> > >       C:\opencv231\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 552

Comment: Did you try to compile your code with all warnings enabled and with debugging information (with GCC that would be `gcc -Wall -g`)? Did you try to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`)?

Comment: The opencv libraries I have are visual studio only.  I am stepping through with a debugger but it's not immediately clear to me why this is failing. It seems to be an error thrown from opencv itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Cause:

```
cv::Mat *test_bug = new cv::Mat(img->rows, img->cols, CV_32F);
```

Note the `CV_32F`; that's a floating point matrix.

```
test_bug->at<unsigned char>(0,0) = 4;
```

Note `unsigned char` (or `uchar`) ; now you're treating it like an unsigned char matrix (`CV_8U`).

#### Fix:

So if your matrix is supposed to be floating-point, you need to access elements with:

```
test_bug->at<float>(0,0) = 4;
```

Or, if you wanted to declare a `uchar` matrix:

```
cv::Mat *test_bug = new cv::Mat(img->rows, img->cols, CV_8U);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code exactly, and had no trouble, but I'm using the OpenCV trunk on Linux.

A few things to try:

**What happens if instead of an unsigned char you use a float:**

```
test_bug->at< float >(0, 0) = 4.0;
```

**Declare the object on the stack to see if the behavior changes.**

```
Mat test_bug(img->size(), CV_32F);
test_bug.at< unsigned char >(0, 0) = 4; // this will work, but it will only set one byte of the 32-bit floating point number.
```

**NOTE :** Only setting the first byte of the `float` pixel you will see some interesting data because the `at()` function advances the pixel pointer by the number bytes you specified for the type (in your case `sizeof(float) == 4`). You could (not that you would want to) set the floating point value using an `unsigned int` like so:

```
test_bug->at< unsigned int >(0, 0) = 0x41CA0000; // same as 25.25 in IEEE 754...
```

Also, make sure that `img->size() != Size(0, 0)` that could also be something that is a problem.

Hope that is helpful!