# CV::Mat causing runtime error - OpenCV Error - Assertion failed

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a image processing project and i am encountering a crash in the system. This is the error that keeps popping:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)si
>   ze.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channel
>   s()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3
>   ) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file d:\libs\opencv-249\build\i
>   nclude\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 537

I was able to find that the following bit of code is making the problem

```
samples = (src.size(), src.type());
imshow ("source" , src);
for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
  for( int z = 0; z < 3; z++){

      samples.at<float>((y + (x*src.rows)), z) = src.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[z];}
```

`samples` is a Mat object that is declared in the header file of this class.

I also referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112996/cvmat-causes-crash-when-assigned-to-with-atunsigned-char0-0) but even though the error is the same the code that is causing the crash is not the same as mine. But the awkward thing is that this exact piece of code works fine within another function, but when i try to include the same code within a method that belongs to a class it is making this error.

I am clueless. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Whats src.type()? Why do you access samples as "floats" and src as "Vec3b", when they both have the same type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want `samples` to be a matrix with:

```
# rows     : src.rows * src.cols
# cols     : src.channels() // it's probably 3,
type       : CV_32F (float)
# channels : 1 (single channel matrix)
```

You than access the rows of `samples` using the index of the position `(r,c)` in `src`:

```
int index = r * src.cols + c;
```

For example, if `src` is a `2x4` 3 channel image (with random values):

[image]

You want `samples` to be a `8x3` single channel float matrix:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Init src image
    Mat src(2, 4, CV_8UC3);
    randu(src, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    // Init samples image
    // # rows = src.rows * src.cols
    // # cols = src.channels()
    // type   =  CV_32FC1 (single channel float, while src type is 3 channel CV_8U)
    Mat samples(src.rows * src.cols, src.channels(), CV_32FC1);

    for (int r = 0; r < src.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < src.cols; ++c)
        {
            int index = r * src.cols + c;
            for (int channel = 0; channel < src.channels(); ++channel)
            {
                samples.at<float>(index, channel) = src.at<Vec3b>(r, c)[channel];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "SRC: " << endl << src << endl << endl;
    cout << "SAMPLES: " << endl << samples << endl << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and explanation. It helped me out a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

In the call `samples.at<float>((y + (x*src.rows)), z)` you access the image at a point where `x = z` and `y = (y + (x*src.rows)`.

The highest value for y you can get is `(y + (x*src.rows)) = (src.rows-1 + ((src.cols-1)*src.rows)) = src.rows*src.cols-1`. This is much higher than the maximum allowed value of src.cols-1, so OpenCV throws an assertion telling you that this is out of the range of the image.

I don't know why it works in one part of the code and not in another, but this is clearly an issue.

Also, whats src.type()? Why do you access samples as "floats" and src as "Vec3b", when they both have the same type? This seems to be very dangerous to do, as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake. It saved my time a lot. I changed the code as `samples.at<float>((x + (y*src.cols)), z) = src.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[z];` Now it works fine. Plus the reason why i use "float" instead of  "Vec3b" is that, i am using the "samples" as input data for kmeans clustering, which does not accept "Vec3b" type.

Comment: @nickY I'm not sure that your changed code works... you still have the same problem , I think. Why not change it to `samples.at<float>(y, x)`? Also, if you use float, you should initialize samples with `samples = (src.size(), CV_F32)` instead of `samples = (src.size(), src.type())`.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that. I did change it as `Mat samples (src.rows * src.cols, 3, CV_32F);` Therefore it works without any errors. Thank you again for pointing it out.